# MATLAB copyobj reverses the order of objects?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I was debugging a large graphics project and finally reduced the problem into the following MWE. Somehow MATLAB's `copyobj` reverses the order of the graphics objects when it copies them to a new figure.

```
X = [1 2; 4 4];
Y = [2 -4; -4 2];
figure;
hold on;
colors = [1 0 0; 0 1 0];
lines  = [];
for idx = 1:size(X, 2)
    l = plot(X(:, idx), Y(:, idx), 'Color', colors(idx, :), 'linewidth', 10);
    lines = [lines l];
end
hold off;
```

gives

[image]

As expected, the green line that was drawn later is on top of the red line. Then I copy these two lines into a new figure.

```
figure;
a = axes;
copyobj(lines, a);
view(a);
```

gives

[image]

Now the red is above the green.

Does anybody know the reason behind this? To get the order correct, can I just reverse the object order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`copyobj` copies the objects in the reverse order.

 To get the correct order, use `copyobj(lines(end:-1:1), a);` or  `copyobj(fliplr(lines), a);` instead of `copyobj(lines, a);`

---

**An advice on your code:-**

Instead of growing the size of `lines` on every iteration, **[pre-allocate](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/preallocating-arrays.html)** it as shown below:

```
lines = gobjects(1,2);
for idx = 1:size(X, 2)
    lines(idx) = plot(X(:, idx), Y(:, idx), 'Color', colors(idx, :), 'linewidth', 10);
end
```

Read the documentation of [**`gobjects()`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gobjects.html) and [**Graphics Arrays**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/concatenating-handles-into-arrays.html) for details.

And if using the loop is not a requirement for you, you can simply use the following:

```
% Following is to set the Colors that you specified
set(gca, 'ColorOrder', colors);
% Now plotting the data 
lines = plot(X,Y,'linewidth',10 );
```